# Entity Framework 5. Multiple Include. Is this possible?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create a multiple include method in my repository to use as follows:

```
repository.Include<Post>(x => x.Images, x => x.Tags).First(x => x.Id == 1)
```

I tried something as:

```
public IQueryable<T> Include<T>(params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] paths) where T : class {
  return paths.Aggregate(_context.Set<T>(), (x, path) => x.Include(path));
} // Include
```

But I get the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'.

Note that the original include is the following:

public static IQueryable Include(
  this IQueryable source, 
  Expression> path
) where T : class;

Can I make this work without turning my repository method into static?

Thank You,

Miguel

Comment: You only have to do `_context.Set<T>().AsQueryable()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really want to create your own `.Include` non-extension method that allows for multiple paths in one call, internally translating to the already provided `.Include` method, you can do something like

```
public IQueryable<T> Include<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] paths)
    where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
    foreach (var path in paths)
        query = query.Include(path);
    return query;
}
```

This is pretty close to what you have already, but avoids the pitfall with `Enumerable.Aggregate` that you encountered: you'd have the same problem if you replace `IQueryable<T> query` with `var query` in my version.

Note that using many `.Include` may harm performance. If it does in your situation, you can rewrite it to use multiple queries, which you can run one after the other in a transaction.

Personally, as you can call the already provided `.Include` extension method (`using System.Data.Entity;`) on any `IQueryable`, I'd just write it as:

```
repository.Posts.Include(x => x.Images).Include(x => x.Tags).First(x => x.Id == 1)
```

Comment: Why do you say that many Include may harm preformance? I turned off Lazy Loading so sometimes I need to use Include. And of course I will include only the entities I need. I can include Tags and not Images if I don't need Images. Am I missing something from your words?

Comment: The reason why I am not using repository.Posts.Include(x => x.Images).Include(x => x.Tags) is because I am using a generic repository. Of course your approach is also a good one. In fact I have use it in the past. I just opted , in this case, for using a Generic repository.

Comment: @Shapper `a.Include(b).Include(c).Include(d).Include(e)` is translated to an SQL `select * from a left join b on b... = a... left join c on c... = a... left join d... = a... left join e... = a...` Let's say `a` has one record, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` each have 100. So you want to load 401 records into memory. EF will however have to filter through 100.000.000 records in the SQL result set in order to get the 401 entities.

Comment: @Shapper In such a case, even if lazy loading is turned off, you can still use [`EntityCollection.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896370.aspx), which does not have that problem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, EF sometimes does manage to come up with complicated queries that give less rows, but they still perform a lot worse than simpler separate queries :)

Comment: When you say to use EntityCollection.Load do you mean something like: //  var post = context.First(x => x.Id == 1);   var tags = context.Entry(post).Collection(x => x.Tags).Query().Select(x => x.Name);  // If post has only 20 tags isn't better or fine to use Include? Thank You, Miguel

Comment: @Shapper I meant `((EntityCollection<Tag>)p.Tags).Load();`, which looks much better when `p.Tags` is actually declared as `EntityCollection<Tag>` so that you don't need the cast, and so that you don't have to rely on implementation details. When using `.Entry().Collection()`, which is actually a much better method (thanks for reminding me, I forgot it existed), there's [`DbCollectionEntry.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcollectionentry.load%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), so it should be `context.Entry(post).Collection(p => p.Tags).Load();`.

Comment: @Shapper As for which is better, it depends. If you expect that your query won't start returning significantly larger data sets, and it performs well with `.Include()`, by all means continue using `.Include()` :)

Comment: I see ... I was using context.Entry(post).Collection(x => x.Tags).Query().Select(x => x.Name) just as an example that I could also query it ... Thank You for the help.

Comment: Hey I am using the similar pattern and have lazy loading and proxy turned off. When I check the SQL generated by EF, it has all the children included in one query. But the child object still not getting populated. Can you please help me?

Comment: @BrikeshKumar Please don't post questions as if they were answers. You can delete what you put here, and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ICollection<SomeClass> Filter(string name, int skip, int take,out int total, params Expression<Func<SomeClass, object>>[] includeProperties) {
      IQueryable<SomeClass> query = Session.All<SomeClass>().AsNoTracking();
      //query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, property) => current.Include(property));
      foreach (var property in includeProperties){
          query = query.Include(property);
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)){
          query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name));
          var page = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
              .Skip(skip)
              .Take(take)
              .GroupBy(p => new{Total = query.Count()})
              .FirstOrDefault();
         total = (page != null) ? page.Key.Total : 0;
         if (page == null) {
            return new List<SomeClass>();
         }
         return  page.ToList();
      } else {
          var page = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
              .Skip(skip)
              .Take(take)
              .GroupBy(p => new { Total = query.Count() })
              .FirstOrDefault();
          total = (page != null) ? page.Key.Total : 0;
          if (page == null) {
             return new List<SomeClass>();
          }
          return page.ToList();
      }
  }
```

Comment: okay..earlier I was getting the count and the result in one query.But that doesn't work when lazy loading is off. Since the I am projecting, the includes don't get executed. After removing the group by it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the shortest way is as follows:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Acts similar of .Include() LINQ method, but allows to include several object properties at once.
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] paths)
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var path in paths)
            query = query.Include(path);

        return query;
    }
}
```