# EF LINQ include multiple and nested entities

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Ok, I have tri-leveled entities with the following hierarchy: Course -> Module -> Chapter

Here was the original EF LINQ statement:

```
Course course = db.Courses
                .Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters))
                .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

Now, I want to include another entity called Lab which is associated with a course.

How do I include the Lab entity?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Course course = db.Courses
                .Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters) && i.Lab)
                .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

Any ideas on including the 2nd Entity?

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Adding another `.Include` should work unless you mean that the additional include is a grandchild of Course. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities) or a [better option is this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819856/entity-framework-5-multiple-include-is-this-possible)

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3356541

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Have you tried just adding another `Include`:

```
Course course = db.Courses
                .Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters))
                .Include(i => i.Lab)
                .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

Your solution fails because `Include` doesn't take a boolean operator

```
Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters) &&          i.Lab)
                           ^^^                  ^             ^ 
                          list           bool operator    other list
```

**Update**
To learn more, download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and look through the samples.
I think it is the quickest way to get familiar with Linq and Lambda.

As a start - the difference between `Select` and `Include` is that that with a Select you decide ***what*** you want to return (aka projection). The Include is a ***Eager Loading*** function, that tells Entity Framework that you want it to include data from other tables.

The Include syntax can also be in string. Like this:

```
           db.Courses
            .Include("Module.Chapter")
            .Include("Lab")
            .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

But the samples in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) explains this better.

Comment: Appreciate it! Where can I learn more of this? I'm especially interested in the difference between Include and Select

Comment: Only this one worked for me: `.Include("Module.Chapter")`. Any idea why would that be?

Comment: @JoSmo you need to import the namespace `System.Data.Enity` to access the extensionmethod. more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: You might need to disable lazy loading to avoid infinite loop errors: `dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: upvoted for mentioning the brilliant linqpad, and tip to use System.Data.Entity, thx Jens

Answer (score 107):

In Entity Framework Core (`EF.core`) you can use `.ThenInclude` for including next levels.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
    .ToList();
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

*Note:*
Say you need multiple `ThenInclude()` on `blog.Posts`, just repeat the `Include(blog => blog.Posts)` and do another `ThenInclude(post => post.Other)`.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Other)
 .ToList();
```

Comment: In EF.core I seem to not be able to do .Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters)), specifically the .Select inside .Include.  Can anyone confirm or speak to?

Comment: @ttugates What do you intent to do with this select? I think what you want to do is exactly what you do with `ThenInclude` in EF core. Perhaps make a question with a good example, so that we can answer it.

Comment: [@Nick N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869033/nick-n) - [Entity Framework Linq Query: How to Where on Multiple Nav Properties and Select from 3rd Nav Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870578/entity-framework-linq-query-how-to-where-on-multiple-nav-properties-and-select).  Because what I Select is not what I am matching on, the Includes are not necessary so the question is tangential.  My question may be too "narrow" but appreciate any help.

Comment: Ah.  Actually, .ThenInclude() does work.  Just takes forever for the intellisense to display the related tables.

Answer (score 25):

You can also try

```
db.Courses.Include("Modules.Chapters").Single(c => c.Id == id);
```

Comment: Thanks - the dot notation in the string very useful

Comment: This can be useful, but, one reason not to use this is ease of refactoring later: if you rename the "Chapters" entity at some point, the other example will automatically be renamed. Another is that errors will be found sooner: at compile time, not run time.

Comment: @MGOwen I agree with your comment. However, could use: `db.Courses.Include($"{nameof(Modules)}.{nameof(Chapters)}").Single(c => c.Id == id);`  as well.

Answer (score 24):

`Include` is a part of fluent interface, so you can write multiple `Include` statements each following other

```
 db.Courses.Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapters))
           .Include(i => i.Lab)
           .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: appreciate it! could you point me to where I can learn more of this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the syntax is if Modules has multiple tables you want to join? Say it links to Chapters and something else?

Answer (score 6):

One may write an extension method like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Includes an array of navigation properties for the specified query 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">The query to include navigation properties for that</param>
    /// <param name="navProperties">The array of navigation properties to include</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params string[] navProperties)
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var navProperty in navProperties)
            query = query.Include(navProperty);

        return query;
    }
```

And use it like this even in a generic implementation:

```
string[] includedNavigationProperties = new string[] { "NavProp1.SubNavProp", "NavProp2" };

var query = context.Set<T>()
.Include(includedNavigationProperties);
```

Comment: I was trying your answer, but it's throwing stackoverflowexceptions due to an infinite loop with itself.

Comment: @VictoriaS., you can rename the extension method so that it doesn't interfere with the real `Include`

Answer (score 4):

this is from my project

```
 var saleHeadBranch = await _context.SaleHeadBranch
 .Include(d => d.SaleDetailBranch)
 .ThenInclude(d => d.Item)
 .Where(d => d.BranchId == loginTkn.branchId)
 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == id);
```

Comment: var saleHeadBranch = await _context.SaleHeadBranch
                .Include(d => d.SaleDetailBranch)
                .Include("SaleDetailBranch.Item")
                .Where(d => d.BranchId == loginTkn.branchId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Id == id);

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example.
AccountInfoes is parent for User,
User is parent for Currency and for Country.

```
var accountinfo =  _context.AccountInfoes.Include(a => a.User)
                         .Include(a=>a.User.Currency)
                       .Include(a => a.User.Country)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ai => ai.UserId == userId);
```