# Completing a linq to entites query of a tri-level entity source

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Ok, I have tri-leveled entities with the following hierarchy:
User -> RegisteredVehicle -> MakeSource
----------------------------------->ModelSource
----------------------------------->YearSource (Yes I know, a lookup table for years how horrible.)

A user can have a registered vehicle which itself can have a fk from MakeSource and a fk from ModelSource which holds relevant vehicle data. (Name, Cylinders, Transmission etc)

How can I use a linq query to select a user's information, any registered vehicles he has along with the meta data for the makesource and modelsource tables?

```
var entity = context.AspNetUsers.Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
                .Select(P => P.MakeSource));
```

This gets me as much as the makes but I am still out of luck with the model sources and year sources.

[image]

Comment: Write a second and third include. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764572/ef-linq-include-multiple-and-nested-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to chain the includes:

```
var entity = context.AspNetUsers.Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
            .Select(P => P.MakeSource)).Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
            .Select(P => P.ModelSource)).Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
            .Select(P => P.YearSource));
```