# ´ObjectDisposedException´ when trying to asynchronously retrieve data using EF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous

So I have two tables: `Recipe` and `Step`. One recipe contains multiple Steps.

I have a WPF application and when I load a specific view, I want to asynchronously load data using Entity Framework. So I have this function

```
public async Task<List<recipe>> GetRecipeAsync()
{
    using (var context = new RecipeSystem())
    {
        return await context.recipe.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

In the constructor of my class, I am calling the function above like this:

```
Recipes = _recipeService.GetRecipeAsync().Result;
```

But for some reason, I get an ObjectDisposedException.

[image: Exception]

If I set a breakpoint in `GetRecipeAsync()` and check what value `context.recipe.ToListAsync()` has, it looks fine. Step is available there.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/async-oop-6-disposal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related `Step` object cannot be lazily loaded after the context has been disposed. You could try to load the related entities up front using eager loading:

```
public async Task<List<recipe>> GetRecipeAsync()
{
    using (var context = new RecipeSystem())
    {
        return await context.recipe.Include(x => x.Steps).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Also note that is is considered a good practice to disable the context capturing in `async` service methods by calling the `ConfigureAwait(false)` method. This may also save you from deadlocks: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html.

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked perfectly so far. But how does the syntax look like if I have a 3rd table that references from steps. e.g. One recipe has multiple steps. One steps has multiple actions.

Comment: That's another question really but you could use another Include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764572/ef-linq-include-multiple-and-nested-entities