# Entity Framework Linq Query: How to Where on Multiple Nav Properties and Select from 3rd Nav Property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have the following models with nav propertiers set up in Entity Framework Core:

- CRMLocations (one-to-many) CRMPeoples
- CRMPeoples (one-to-many) CRMEmails
- CRMPeoples (one-to-many) CRMPhones

I have the following working Query:

```
        var iqable = _crmDbContext.CRMPeoples
            .Where(p =>
                p.Name.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
                (from e in p.CRMEmails where e.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(query) select e).Any() ||
                (from h in p.CRMPhones where h.PhoneNumberNormalized.Contains(query) select h).Any())
            .Select(p => new CRMSearchResultDTO()
            {
                PersonName = p.Name,
                LocationName = p.CRMLocations.Name,
            });
```

How can I replace the "(from in where select).Any()" statements to use Linq's lambda syntax?  Must result in 1 SQL statement.  Can use left outter joins, or nested select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var iqable = _crmDbContext.CRMPeoples
        .Where(p =>
            p.Name.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
            p.CRMEmails.Where(e => e.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(query)).Any() ||
            p.CRMPhones.Where(h => h.PhoneNumberNormalized.Contains(query)).Any())
        .Select(p => new CRMSearchResultDTO()
        {
            PersonName = p.Name,
            LocationName = p.CRMLocations.Name,
        });
```

I got this code by using ReSharper's command "Convert LINQ to method chain"

Comment: Oh man, that was so straight forward..  :)  Swore that generated a ton of sql statements last week.  Also, ReSharper has "Convert LINQ to method chain." - Nice.  My very original code was SQL with Left Joins and a bit more complex, "Convert LINQ to method chain." would be very helpful..

Comment: And there is also: instead of writing `p.CRMEmails.Where(e => e.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(query)).Any()` you can write `p.CRMEmails.Any(e => e.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(query))` (it is advised by ReSharper)

Comment: Thx, thats how I would normally write it..  Dunno what I was thinking or why I had problems.