# Entity Framework - Include 3 sublevels of properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 Code-First.
I have four-leveled entities with the following hierarchy:

```
Express(top level) 
    -> Constant(1st sublevel) 
    -> Event(also 1st sublevel) 
         -> Parameter(2nd sublevel) 
              -> Value(3rd sublevel)
```

I can obtain 2 sublevels via

```
db.Expresses.Include(ex=>ex.Constants).Include(ex=>ex.Events.Select(ev=>ev.Parameters));
```

But how can I include third sublevel (Value) in that query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF LINQ include multiple and nested entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764572/ef-linq-include-multiple-and-nested-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Expresses.Include(ex => ex.Constants)
            .Include(ex => ex.Events.Select(ev => ev.Parameters.Select(par => par.Value)));
```

Please ensure using System.Data.Entity namespace to get the overrides of Include method.
See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1) for more examples.

Comment: Oh, that was so easy :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use strings

```
db.Expresses.Include("Constants")
            .Include("Events.Parameters.Values")
```