# How to include nested List in asp.net api response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nested-lists

I'm working with a nested list (List inside List) everything is working fine but when I try to get response from Api (GetOrders) it is not showing lists. I try to .include(x=>x.ShopOrdersList) but It is only including "ShopOrdersList" and the second list "OrderSummaries" which is inside  "ShopOrdersList" is not showing.
My model is follow

```
 public class Orders
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public string OwnerCnic { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int TotalSale { get; set; }
    public int TotalProfit { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecover { get; set; }
    public List<ShopOrder> ShopOrdersList { get; set; }
}
public class ShopOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int ShopOrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderBooker { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryMan { get; set; }
    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
    public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelivered { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaymentAdded { get; set; }
    public int TotalProfit { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderSummary> OrderSummaries { get; set; }
}
public class OrderSummary
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderSummaryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public int PcsInCtn { get; set; }
    public int OnePcsPurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public int Ctns { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller code is

```
// GET: api/Orders
    public IQueryable<Orders> GetOrders()
    {
        return db.Orders.Include(x => x.ShopOrdersList);
    }
```

This is response that I'm getting.
[image: Response]
Now I want to include "OrderSummaries" list. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer [EF LINQ include multiple and nested entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764572/ef-linq-include-multiple-and-nested-entities)
Its saying you can call `ThenInclude` to add nested entries

```
 public IQueryable<Orders> GetOrders()
    {
        return db.Orders.Include(x => x.ShopOrdersList).ThenInclude(y=>y.OrderSummaries);
    }
```

Comment: There is not any "ThenInclude" extension method

Comment: Have you checked the link I mentioned?

Comment: Yes I have checked that link from that I get a clue to use "Select" extension method which works perfectly. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Cool, I am glad that helped :)