# optional include with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, include, eager-loading

I'm working on a manager. Depending on the conditions some include must be enforced in order to get eager loading. But sometime I don't want all the data so the includes should not be applied.

This is what I've got so far.

```
//INFO : public partial class Entities : DbContext

        var Database = new Entities();
        var result = Database.Department;
        if (includeHospitalEmployee) {  result.Include(a => a.HospitalEmployee); }
        if (includeQuickScans) {  result.Include(a => a.QuickScan);  }

        return result;
```

This doesn't work. The includes aren't loaded, although the `includebooleans` are set to true. Query results in;

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Extent1].[Discipline] AS [Discipline], 
    [Extent1].[FinancialCode] AS [FinancialCode], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[DepartmentManagerId] AS [DepartmentManagerId], 
    [Extent1].[Show] AS [Show], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Department] AS [Extent1]
```

But strange enough if i do this, all include are working

```
//INFO  : public partial class Entities : DbContext
        var Database = new Entities();
        var result = this.businessManagersFactory.Database.Department.Include(a => a.QuickScan);;
        if (includeHospitalEmployee) {  result.Include(a => a.HospitalEmployee); }
        if (includeQuickScans) {  result.Include(a => a.QuickScan);  }

        return result;
```

see the query

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Project1].[Discipline] AS [Discipline], 
    [Project1].[FinancialCode] AS [FinancialCode], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[DepartmentManagerId] AS [DepartmentManagerId], 
    [Project1].[Show] AS [Show], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Project1].[StartDateTime] AS [StartDateTime], 
    [Project1].[EndDateTime] AS [EndDateTime], 
    [Project1].[Shared] AS [Shared], 
    [Project1].[ScanStatus] AS [ScanStatus], 
    [Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Project1].[Count] AS [Count], 
    [Project1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
    [Project1].[HospitalEmployeeId] AS [HospitalEmployeeId], 
    [Project1].[DepartmentId] AS [DepartmentId]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
        [Extent1].[Discipline] AS [Discipline], 
        [Extent1].[FinancialCode] AS [FinancialCode], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent1].[DepartmentManagerId] AS [DepartmentManagerId], 
        [Extent1].[Show] AS [Show], 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[StartDateTime] AS [StartDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[EndDateTime] AS [EndDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[Shared] AS [Shared], 
        [Extent2].[ScanStatus] AS [ScanStatus], 
        [Extent2].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent2].[Count] AS [Count], 
        [Extent2].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
        [Extent2].[HospitalEmployeeId] AS [HospitalEmployeeId], 
        [Extent2].[DepartmentId] AS [DepartmentId], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM  [dbo].[Department] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[QuickScan] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Code] = [Extent2].[DepartmentId]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Code] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

Why is this behaviour and how to get it working properly?

regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 5. Multiple Include. Is this possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819856/entity-framework-5-multiple-include-is-this-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to Visual Studio to confirm but you will probably find that assigning the return from the call to `Include` will sort it - it will be something like a `QueryObject` that implements `IQueryable`

```
var Database = new Entities();
IQueryable<Department> result = Database.Departments;
if (includeHospitalEmployee) { result = result.Include(a => a.HospitalEmployee); }
if (includeQuickScans) { result = result.Include(a => a.QuickScan);  }

return result;
```